# Toggle/Change Hidden Developer Options Settings Programmatically

Tags: android, android-settings, android-developer-api

I know that settings can be changed programmatically this way:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.Secure.ADB_ENABLED, 1);
```

But there are some settings in `Developer Options` which are not provided neither in `Settings.Secure`, `Settings.Global` nor `Settings.System`.

For example `Simulate color space` option which was added from `Api 21`
[image: Simulate Color Space]

Are there other ways to access it?

Comment: Please, let me know if you had any success with this.

Comment: @AdamMcquiff unfortunately not :(